# There's an extra semicolon in the Contact Us popup for resetting passwords

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

This is what the popup says if you select *I lost my password* from the [Contact Us page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact).

> If you have lost your password, please visit our password recovery page to reset it.;
>
> [image]

I think someone accidentally forgot a `;` in there.

Also happens if I select "My question or answer was denied":

> [image]

Comment: +1 "I think someone accidentally a ;"

Comment: Nah, it's missing a ')'

Comment: What is this blasphemous shape surrounding the semicolon!?

Comment: @StephenTG It's a unicorn.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Next time I'll roll back your edit for ridiculing my orthogonal aesthetics!

Comment: Surely it's just a 'friendly' statement telling you how to visit the password recovery page.. with a wink ;

Comment: @slhck oops though it was; by mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These typos will be fixed in the next deploy.